# Protractor-Jasmine e2e tests fails in jenkins with driver instance does not have valid session ID

Tags: jenkins, jasmine, protractor, sessionid

e2e tests run fine in local but when run on Jenkins most of it fails with invalid session id
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfj59.png)

Comment: can you attach the actual error stack

Comment: Yes. Please check the image attached. Just so you know my config file is set for suites in spite of specs. I am not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: look in your project if you're using `browser.close()` anywhere

Comment: for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428909/9150146